# What are these lines depicting movement in a cartoon called?

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for these curved lines that represent head motion?

[image: Rosie Cleaning Up]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_lines)

> *In comics, **motion lines** (also known as **movement lines, action lines, speed lines, hites** or **zip ribbons**) are the **abstract lines** that appear behind a moving object or person, parallel to its direction of movement, to make it appear as if it is moving quickly.*

---

I can't find a corresponding (domain-specific?) definition of ***abstract lines*** as used above, but I'm guessing it's intended to imply *lines which convey an abstract quality such as movement, emotion, etc. - rather than something "material", such as might be captured by a photographic image*.

By implication therefore, exclamation marks or a lightbulb drawn above a cartoon character's head (indicating surprise, or a sudden inspiration) ought to *also* be called "abstract" lines / glyphs / punctuation marks, but I've never come across any such usage myself.

---

For anyone who thinks this is "Quiite Interesting" (such as me, now my attention is focused on it), I also found [this post on Pinterest...](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/64246732161084087/?lp=true)

> ***Hites, Vites, Dites,*** or **Briffits**.
>
> ***Hites*** are horizontal lines to indicate speed or movement. **Vites** are vertical lines that add shine on a floor or an icy pond. **Dites** are diagonal lines to represent the reflection in a window or mirror. And **Briffits** are simply cloud-shaped dust clouds.

Fascinating stuff, domain-specific terminology.

Comment: @Lambie: I bothered because ***abstract lines*** was used as part of the Wikipedia *definition*, not simply as an alternative name having the same meaning as ***motion lines, action lines, speed lines, hites, zip ribbons***. And I went on to provide supplementary info regarding ***hites*** because at least *some* people (though apparently not you) might well think that's highly relevant to the usage.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by that. Assuming we're both competent native speakers, how come it's "obvious" to you that ***abstract*** here means *denoting an abstract quality that's not normally visible*, but to me it's at least an "unusual" usage that I had to think through ***in context*** to see what it meant? And if it strikes *me* as unusual, wouldn't it be even more likely to be somewhat opaque to a non-native speaker such as might be reading this answer?

Comment: What else? How about [*If **symbols** are the most focused and explicit kind of conceptual imagery, at the opposite end of the scale of precision are **abstract** images*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+most+focused+and+explicit+kind%22)? In *my* understanding, things like ***exclamation marks*** as referenced in my answer are definitely symbols (as is ***lightbulb***, in the context of being drawn over a cartoon characters head). Whether we should call "hites" ***symbols*** or ***abstract images*** (given they're presented there as complete opposites) is a quandary to me.

Comment: I would have stuck with just *motion lines* and left the discussion about *abstract lines* out of it—aside from just having it as part of the quotation. Perhaps I think how @Lambie does, although I can't tell with the comments now missing. My emotional reaction to *abstract lines* in this context is to find the term nonsensical and ridiculous—and a distraction from an otherwise simple answer—in particular if no other sources corroborate the Wikipedia entry. (There are also many other sources that discuss *motion lines*.) But, that's just my personal opinion . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford: Like I said, that Wikipedia entry *defines* "motion lines" as "abstract lines". Since "abstract" in that context didn't mean much to me, I tried to dig a little deeper (without much success, obviously). The issue as being discussed here centred on Lambie claiming that the meaning was obvious, and therefore didn't need to be further explained. But as to *what* that obvious meaning might be, I'm still as much in the dark as ever - essentially I'm with you in finding the term nonsensical and ridiculous, but since I'd *cited* it I felt I had to at least *try* to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the term you're looking for is 'emanata'. It only includes lines coming out of the character, not motion though.